# Cordova - can you override plist NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription values set by a plugin?

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, info.plist, cordova-cli

**TLDR;** With Cordova, is there a way to overwrite any `Info.plist` values such as  `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription` that a plugin may have set? (i.e. maybe with a hook?)

---

A lot of Cordova plugins attempt to configure plist values such as `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`. For example:

```
    <config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription">
      <string>Please authorize photo library to save pictures.</string>
    </config-file>

    <config-file target ="*-Info.plist" parent="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription">
      <string>Please authorize photo library to save pictures.</string>
    </config-file>
```

If multiple plugins do this, we end up with multiple values in `platforms/ios/ios.json`, for example:

```
{
  "prepare_queue": {
    "installed": [],
    "uninstalled": []
  },
  "config_munge": {
    "files": {
      "*-Info.plist": {
        "parents": {
          "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription": [
            {
              "xml": "<string>Send photos in your messages to the app.</string>",
              "count": 1
            },
            {
              "xml": "<string>We allow you to send us photos via our in-app messenger</string>",
              "count": 144
            }
          ],
           ...
```

This is problematic, as it seems that Cordova will only copy the value of the *last* item for any key (`NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`) into the `Info.plist` file.

Another issue is that setting these settings yourself in `config.xml` will not take precedence to the ones the plugin has set. It just depends which values are *last* in `platforms/ios/ios.json`.

So there are two problems here:

1. A plugin can provide a bad description (such as the `cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing` plugin), which [Apple can reject you for](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin/issues/1030)

   You then have no way to override this that I can see.
2. If multiple plugins provide a value for the same Info.plist value, only the last one is used. That is a problem to me, as you can't really control which is the "last" one.

So my question is - Is there a way in config.xml or a hook, to provide the actual Info.plist settings that will be used?

(I'm currently using Cordova CLI 8.1.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [cordova-custom-config](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config) to override the usage description messages which have been inserted by Cordova: 
since `cordova-custom-config` applies its changes (by default) on Cordova's `after_prepare` hook, it will execute afterwards so its changes will take precedence.

Install it into your project:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-custom-config
```

Then define a `<custom-config-file>` block in your `config.xml`, for example:

```
<custom-config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription">
    <string>My override description</string>
</custom-config-file>
```

Note: `cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing` does provide a mechanism to override its own default descriptions - it [defines `<preference>`s](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin/blob/master/plugin.xml#L44) which can be overriden using a variable during plugin installation, for example:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing --variable PHOTO_LIBRARY_ADD_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="Some description" --variable PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="Some other description"
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I didn't know about `cordova-custom-config`.   Ah, yes, those variables for `cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing` were added just the other day after I reported this issue to the project :-)